# Memory leak with a HashMap on Android

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I'm trying to fix a memory leak that I'm not understanding how it happens, maybe with your help I could get to the solution.
I have a ListFragment and a FileInfo class that stores the data for each list item. In this FileInfo class (it's to big to post it here) I have following:

```
public static final HashMap<String, FileInfo> sFileInfoObjectList = new CacheLinkedHashMap<String, FileInfo>();
```

I use this cache so I must not construct each FileInfo again each time. Each time my ListFragmnet get's reloaded FileInfo.getFileInfo(...) is called, if the FileInfo is in the cache it is returned, otherwise a new one is constructed. As I can see with DDMS, the heap of the Application is growing each time the ListFragment gets reloaded. Why am I sure that sFileInfoObjectList is leaking? Because when I call sFileInfoObjectList.clear() in the onDestroy() method of the ListFragment the heaps does not grow. I also checked the size of sFileInfoObjectList to see if it is growing but it's not, so this is really confusing for me now.

Comment: And we are supposed to read your mind or conjure up the answer with a magic spell? You have to show us what you did, at least the relevant parts, otherwise nobody can help you.

Comment: You are supposed to use your experience to show others the way to get to a solution.

Comment: How can anybody find a solution if nobody has the slightest idea what the problem might be?

Comment: @XaverKapeller I think, you are right (also with your comment to my answer). This is a poor question and must be updated. Otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: And on a side note: Are you really sure that there is a memory leak in the first place? Just because the heap grows each time doesn't mean there is anything wrong, in fact I would expect that.

Comment: Does your application crash at some point? If yes, then most likely you are dealing with a memory leak. If your app does not crash then I seriously doubt that there is anything wrong.

Comment: It crashes with an out of memory after reloading the list many many times. I'm sure that the map is the cause because as I said calling clear() reduces the heap size again to the size it had before starting to reloading the listFragment

Comment: Well then the problem seems to be that you are putting too much data in the `Map`. It has nothing to do with a memory leak. Try to debug step-by-step, and look at the data in the `Map`. Try to figure out what's going wrong. Additionally: You really should use an [**LruCache**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) instead of a `Map`. A `LruCache` is actually designed to do what you want from it and it is almost certainly the solution to your `OutOfMemoryException`.

Answer (score 1):

**You declared your field as static!**

This way, all instances of the class, in which this static field is declared, share a single instance of the hash map. In a long running application this map might grow and grow and grow.

The solution is to make it an instance field by removing the `static` keyword. Now each time, when the instances having this field are eligible for garbage collection, the map will also be collected.

And by the way: Don't name map type fields as "list"!

Comment: I think @David is fully aware of what `static` does, I think he did that on purpose because he wants the `Map` to be `static`.

Comment: But it must be static, it's a cache, it's a global cache. I'm listing for example the files in Diredtoy A, for each file in this directory I create a FileInfo, creating the FileInfo costs time so I put them in the cache. The leak is happening while reloading Directory A, I don't reaload other new directories, so the number of elements in the hashmap stays always the same but the heap is still growing.

Comment: @David: Then Xaver is totally right. This is a poor question, not showing us the relevant part of your code. I will now also vote to close it.